# Only one error left in my code, 

Tags: fortran, fortran90

```
PROGRAM MPI
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nn=100

DOUBLE PRECISION h, L
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (2*nn) :: y, ynew
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (nn) :: qnew,vnew
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (2*nn) :: k1,k2,k3,k4
INTEGER j, k
INTEGER i
INTEGER n

n=100 !particles
L=2.0d0
h=1.0d0/n
y(1)=1.0d0

DO k=1,2*n          ! time loop

   CALL RHS(y,k1)
   CALL RHS(y+(h/2.0d0)*k1,k2)
   CALL RHS(y+(h/2.0d0)*k2,k3)
   CALL RHS(y+h*k3,k4)

   ynew(1:2*n)=y(1:2*n) + (k1 + 2.0d0*(k2 + k3) + k4)*h/6.0d0
END DO
         qnew(1:n)=ynew(1:n)
    vnew(1:n)=ynew(n+1:2*n)

    DO i=1,n
       IF (qnew(i).GT. L) THEN
       qnew(i) = qnew(i) - L
       ENDIF
    END DO

     write(*,*) 'qnew=', qnew(1:n)
     write(*,*) 'vnew=', vnew(1:n)

     END PROGRAM MPI

    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    !   Right hand side of the ODE
    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             SUBROUTINE RHS(y,z)

             IMPLICIT NONE
             INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nn=100
             DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (2*nn) :: y
             DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (2*nn) :: z
             DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (nn) :: F
             DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (nn) :: g
             INTEGER n
             INTEGER m
             n=100
             m=1/n

     z(1:n)=y(n+1:2*n)
     CAll FORCE(g,F)
     z(n+1:2*n)=F(1:n)/m

             RETURN
             END
     !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     !      Force acting on each particle
     !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

              SUBROUTINE FORCE(g,F)

                         IMPLICIT NONE

                INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nn=100
                DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (nn) :: F
                DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (nn) :: q
                DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (nn) :: g
                DOUBLE PRECISION u
                INTEGER j, e
                INTEGER n
                n=100
                e=1/n

                DO j=2,n+1

                 CALL deriv((abs(q(j)-q(j-1)))/e,u)
                 g(j-1)=((y(j)-y(j-1))/(abs(y(j)-y(j-1))))*u
                 CALL deriv((abs(q(j)-q(j+1)))/e,u)
                 g(j+1)=((y(j)-y(j+1))/(abs(y(j)-y(j+1))))*u

                 F(j)=g(j-1)+g(j+1)

                END DO
              RETURN
              END

              SUBROUTINE deriv(c,u,n)

                         IMPLICIT NONE

                INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
                DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(n), INTENT(IN) :: c
                DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(n), INTENT(OUT) :: u
                INTEGER, PARAMETER :: p=2
                INTEGER, PARAMETER :: cr=100
                INTEGER :: i
                DOUBLE PRECISION L
                L=2.0d0

                DO i= 1,n
                      IF  (c(i) .LE. L) THEN
                          u(i)=cr*(L*(c(i)**(-p))-L**(1-p))
                      ELSE IF (c(i) .GT. L)  THEN
                           u(i)=0
                      END IF

                END DO

             RETURN
             END SUBROUTINE deriv
```

I am only getting one same error on line 85 and 87. It says:

> y has no implicit type at y(j-1) ans at y(j+1).

Comment: Usually, posting the actual errors the compiler gives helps

Comment: That "only" one error left is quite a whopper -- you are making calcluations with y (and, it turns out, q) except that you've never set any values in q anywhere in the code.  When you call deriv((abs(q(j)-q(j-1))/e, u), what numbers is it supposed to use there?  Why?  When you call g(j-1)=((y(j)-y(j-1))/abs(y(j)-y(j-1)))), you haven't even *declared* what type y is, much less plugged any values into there.  What is supposed to go there?  How would `subroutine force` know that?

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot wrong here.  We can point out some of the things, but you're going to have to sit down with a book and learn about programming, starting with smaller programs and getting them right, then building up.

Let's look at the last routine in the code you posted above.  I've changed the syntax of some of the variable declarations just to make it shorter so more fits on screen at once.

```
 SUBROUTINE deriv(c,u)
 IMPLICIT NONE
 DOUBLE PRECISION :: deriv, c, u
 INTEGER :: p, x, cr, n

 L=2.0d0
 cr=100
 p=2
 n=100

 DO i= 1,n
 IF  (c(i).LE. L) THEN
     u(c)=cr*(L*c^(-p)-L^(1-p))
     ELSE IF (c(i) .GT. L)  THEN
     u(c)=0
 END IF

 RETURN
 END
```

So you've made deriv a double precision variable, but it's also the name of the subroutine.  That's an error; maybe you meant to make this a function which returns a double precision value; then you're almost there, you'd need to change the procedure header to `FUNCTION DERIV(c,u)` -- but you never set deriv anywhere.  So likely that should just be left out.  So let's just get rid of that `DOUBLE PRECISION deriv` declaration.  Also, L, which is used, is never declared, and x, which isn't, is declared.

Then you pass in to this subroutine two variables, c and u, which you define to be double precision.  So far so good, but then you start indexing them: eg, `c(i)`.   So they should be arrays of double precisions, not just scalars.   Looking at the do loop, I'm guessing they should both be of size `n` -- which should be passed in, presumably?  .  Also, the do loop is never terminated; there should be an `end do` after the `end if`.

Further, the `^` operator you're using I'm assuming you're using for exponentiation -- but in Fortran, that's `**`, not `^`.  And that `c^(-p)` should (I'm guessing here) be `c(i)**(-p)`?

Finally, you're setting `u(c)` -- but that's not very sensible, as c is an array of double precision numbers.  Even u(c(i)) wouldn't make sense -- you can't index an array with a double precision number.  Presumably, and I'm just guessing here, you mean the value of `u` corresponding to the just-calculated value of `c` -- eg, `u(i)`, not `u(c)`?

So given the above, we'd expect the deriv subroutine to look like this:

```
 SUBROUTINE deriv(c,u,n)
 IMPLICIT NONE
 INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
 DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(n), intent(IN) :: c
 DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(n), intent(OUT) :: u

 INTEGER, PARAMETER :: p=2, cr=100
 DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: L=2.0
 INTEGER :: i

 DO i= 1,n
     IF  (c(i) .LE. L) THEN
         u(i)=cr*(L*c(i)**(-p)-L**(1-p))
     ELSE IF (c(i) .GT. L)  THEN
         u(i)=0
     END IF
 END DO

 RETURN
 END SUBROUTINE deriv
```

Note that in modern fortran, the do loop can be replaced with a where statement, and also you don't need to explicitly pass in the size; so then you could get away with the clearer and shorter:

```
 SUBROUTINE DERIV(c,u)
 IMPLICIT NONE
 DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(:), intent(IN) :: c
 DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(size(c,1)), intent(OUT) :: u

 INTEGER, PARAMETER :: p=2, cr=100
 DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: L=2.0

 WHERE (c <= L)
     u=cr*(L*c**(-p)-L**(1-p))
 ELSEWHERE
     u=0
 ENDWHERE

 RETURN
 END SUBROUTINE DERIV
```

But notice that I've already had to guess three times what you meant in this section of code, and this is only about 1/4th of the total of the code.   Having us try to divine your intention in the whole thing and rewrite accordingly probably isn't the best use of anyone's time; why don't you proceed from here working on one particular thing and ask another question if you have a specific problem.

Comment: I second the advice to read a book.   A good Fortran one is "Fortran 95/2003 Explained" by Metcalf et al.